# Type 'DoWorkEventArgs' is not defined

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Sub Is_Prime(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
```

I get error "Type 'DoWorkEventArgs' is not defined.". What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's wrong?

You probably forgot to Import the `System.ComponentModel` namespace in which the [`DoWorkEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.aspx) class is defined.

You could add the following statement to the top of your file:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
```

Alternatively you could fully qualify the class if you don't want to import the namespace:

```
Public Sub Is_Prime(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
```